# How to auto fit _layout.cshtml in bigger screen size?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 project using bootstrap style.

My _Layout file is basic like this:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="wrap">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      </div>
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                   @RenderBody()
                </div>
            <div>        
         </div>
    </div>
  <div id="footer">
 <div class="container">
    <p class="text-muted">&copy; Company- @DateTime.Now.Date.Year</p>
  </div>
   </div>
```

In my screen size it fits ok, but when i put in a bigger screen it keeps the whole page size and doesnt fit to this bigger screen. What i need to do to auto fit it (to bigger screens).
Ps: Only the top menu and the footer auto fits the size.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this with the large device class prefixes `col-lg-x`? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: @Jasen Yes but i need to do it with the columns? I dont want to change the layout based on the screen size, i just want that the whole layout gets bigger if the screen is bigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can add container style to Site.css 
like:

```
 .container {
    min-width: 100%;
 }
```